# Z Shell "autoload" builtin - what is it good for?

Tags: zsh

I have been using the Z shell for a while now, and I am starting to be curious. One thing I have stumbled at when writing my own functions is "autoload".

According to the zshbuiltins(1) man page `autoload` is "equivalent to `functions -u`" (with an exception), which is "equivalent to `typeset -f`" (with an exception). However, after looking at the autlooad use of, say `functions/Prompts/promptinit`, I think I have an idea what it does.

I think of autoload as, well, kind of "import" statement.

*But why is "autoload foo" superior to "source bar"?* I don't get that.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As stated in the [zsh documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html):

> A function can be marked as undefined
>   using the autoload builtin (or
>   `functions -u` or `typeset -fu`). Such
>   a function has no body. When the
>   function is first executed, the shell
>   searches for its definition using the
>   elements of the `fpath` variable. [...]

**`autoload`** allows for functions to be specified without a body which then get automatically loaded when used ;)

**`source`** however takes as argument a script which is then `executed` in the environment of the current session - i.e. you will retain all changes the script does to the environment, which is not the case when *just* executing the script.

I think this feature is beneficial when having ***lots*** of utilities in functions. It allows for *faster* startup (all the code for the autoload functions need not be loaded) and may keep the memory footprint of the shell *smaller*.

Comment: Ah, faster startup; didn't think of that. Thank you!