# What does autoload do in zsh?

Tags: zsh

I wasn't able to find a documentation for the widely used `autoload` command in zsh. Does anybody can explain it in plain English?

A bit more specific: What does *autoloading of modules* mean, for example in this line:

```
autoload -Uz vcs_info
```

What does it do?

---

I've tried `autoload --help`, `man autoload`, googling - no success. Thanks!

Comment: This question seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493173/z-shell-autoload-builtin-what-is-it-good-for/4493687#4493687

Comment: As a sidebar I'll just comment, since it's not mentioned in the answers and often omitted from web mentions of this feature -- if you're going to create function definitions, you probably will want a dedicated directory for them, and you have to tell zsh how to find that directory -- without clobbering the existing `$FPATH` value. (This is much like extending `$PATH` in most shells.)

E.g. my `.zshrc` has this line:
`export FPATH=$HOME/dotfiles/zsh_functions:$FPATH`

Comment: The man page for `autoload` in zsh can be found in `man zshbuiltins`.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The `autoload` feature is not available in bash, but it is in `ksh` (korn shell) and `zsh`.  On `zsh` see `man zshbuiltins`.

Functions are called in the same way as any other command.  There can be a name conflict between a program and a function.  What `autoload` does is to mark that name as being a function rather than an external program.  The function has to be in a file on its own, with the filename the same as the function name.

```
autoload -Uz vcs_info
```

The `-U` means mark the function `vcs_info` for autoloading and suppress alias expansion.  The `-z` means use `zsh` (rather than `ksh`) style.  See also the `functions` command.

Edit (from comment, as suggested by @ijoseph):

So it records the fact that the name is a function and not an external program - it does not call it unless the `-X` option is used, it just affects the search path when it is called. If the function name does not collide with the name of a program then it is not required. Prefix your functions with something like `f_` and you will probably never need it.

For more detail see http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html.

Comment: I've edited the question due to your answer. But I'm not able to get informations via `man zshbuiltins`, either. The following I get from `zsh --version`: `zsh 5.0.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`.

Comment: OK, I'm using 5.0.5 but on a MacBook.  Did you try `man zsh` then search for `autoload`?  Sorry if you already know this, but to do a search in a `man` page use the same mechanism as you would use in `vim`.  For example, type: `/autoload` when you get the first page displayed.  Type `n` for the next occurrence.

Comment: I don't understand why `man zshbuiltins` does not work for you.  I just checked, and it should be in your version.  Maybe it was the way it is installed, or maybe you need to set `MANPATH`.

Comment: Funny, `man zsh` does not work, too. This is `man -w` for me: `/usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man`. Is smth missed here?

Comment: @malte:  sorry, I couldn't say.  It sounds like something weird happened during the install.  Do a `which zsh`, that should give you some idea where the man pages for it are.  Also, try a `find / -name man 2>/dev/null|more` to get all the man page directories.

Comment: @malte:  I just found this which explains the missing man pages:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/399444/zsh-man-page-documentation-missing-in-packages

Comment: I still don't know what autoload _actually_ does. Does it call a function? Is there any relationship to eval or source? Why would I use `autoload -U compinit` and not simple `compinit`? What does `mark for autloading` mean?

Comment: Above: "What autoload does is to mark that name as being a function rather than an external program.".  So it records the fact that the name is a function and not an external program - it does not call it unless the `-X` option is used, it just affects the search path when it is called.  If the function name does not collide with the name of a program then it is not required.  Prefix your functions with something like `f_` and you will probably never need it.

Comment: @cdarke consider updating the answer with the additional details in the latest comment:  ("It does not call it unless the -X option is used, it just affects the search path when it is called. If the function name does not collide with the name of a program then it is not required. Prefix your functions with something like f_ and you will probably never need it.")

Comment: "Prefix your functions with something like f_ and you will probably never need it" is not true; commands are not automatically searched for in the $FPATH if not found in the $PATH. Only autoloaded names are ever searched for that way.  If your function is defined and then called in the same file, it may work as a script if you put it in $PATH, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: in addtion to what @MarkReed said, autoload is not about giving functions precedence over external programs of the same name. functions always have that precedence. autoload is simply about delaying loading a function until its needed. autoload in fact does define a function - which is wired to finding and loading the actual one from one of the locations in FPATH upon first invocation

Answer (score 105):

`autoload` tells zsh to look for a file in `$FPATH`/`$fpath` containing a *function definition*, instead of a file in `$PATH`/`$path` containing an executable script or binary.

### Script

A script is just a sequence of commands that get executed when the script is run. For example, suppose you have a file called `hello` like this:

```
echo "Setting 'greeting'"
greeting='Hello'
```

If the file is executable and located in one of the directories in your `$PATH`, then you can run it as a script by just typing its name.  But scripts get their own copy of the shell process, so anything they do can't affect the calling shell environment. The assignment to `greeting` above will be in effect only within the script; once the script exits, it won't have had any impact on your interactive shell session:

```
$ hello
Setting 'greeting'
$ echo $greeting

$
```

### Function

A function is instead defined once and stays in the shell's memory; when you call it, it executes inside the current shell, and can therefore have side effects:

```
hello() {
  echo "Setting 'greeting'"
  greeting='Hello'
}

$ hello
Setting 'greeting'
$ echo $greeting
Hello
```

So you use functions when you want to modify your shell environment. The **Zsh Line Editor (ZLE)** also uses functions - when you bind a key to some action, that action is defined as a shell function (which has to be added to ZLE with the `zle -N` command).

If you have a lot of functions, then you might not want to define all of them in your `.zshrc` every time you start a new shell; that slows down shell startup and uses memory to store functions that you might not wind up calling during the lifetime of that shell. So you can instead put the function definitions into their own files, named after the functions they define, put those files into a directory ( I use $HOME/lib/ksh/functions myself), and include the directory in the environment variable `$FPATH` – which, like `$PATH`, is a colon-separated list of directories. (Also like PATH, it's tied to a lowercase equivalent `$fpath`, which presents the same list of directories as an array instead of a single string.)

Zsh comes with a number of standard functions in its install tree, in a set of directories already included in the default value of `$FPATH`. But FPATH and the files in its directories are not part of zsh's normal command lookup; they're ignored *unless* you have first specified that a certain command is the name of a function whose definition can be found by way of FPATH.

*That's* what `autoload` does: it says "Hey, Zsh, this command name here is a function, so when I try to run it, go look for its definition in my FPATH, instead of looking for an executable in my PATH."

The first time you run a command which Zsh determines is an `autoload`ed function, the shell `source`s the definition file. Then, if there's nothing in the file except the function definition, *or* if the shell option `KSH_AUTOLOAD` is set, it proceeds to call the function immediately with the arguments you supplied. But if that option is not set and the file contains any code outside the function definition (such as initialization of variables used by the function), the function is not called automatically. In that case it's up to you to call the function inside the file after defining it, so that first invocation will still happen.

I have my .zshrc autoload all the files in my personal functions directory (not the whole fpath); that takes up much less memory and time than actually loading all of their definitions on startup, while still keeping them available at my prompt without any additional setup. Here is the relevant bit of my zshrc; I put the code into an anonymous function just to avoid adding an extraneous variable to my shell:

```
() {
    # add our local functions dir to the fpath
    local funcs=$HOME/lib/zsh/functions

    # FPATH is already tied to fpath, but this adds
    # a uniqueness constraint to prevent duplicate entries
    typeset -TUg +x FPATH=$funcs:$FPATH fpath
    
    # Now autoload them
    if [[ -d $funcs ]]; then
        autoload ${=$(cd "$funcs" && echo *)}
    fi
}
```

That last `autoload` line is not super robust; it assumes that none of my function file names has funny characters, and that there aren't too many of them to fit on a single command line. But under those constraints it works fine, and is a bit more efficient than a loop.

Comment: Such very useful explanation should be in the mainstream docs/guides because it really explains the "why" behind the features. IMHO every feature should have this purpose-oriented "why" in addition to the usage-oriented manual. Thanks a lot.