# Shell Patterns: re-use matched string (part of the filename)

Tags: bash, shell, file, zsh, rename

I have a directory, filled with `.mp4` files, and another directory `subdir` in it. I know I can move all these files into `subdir` by running following command:

```
mv ./*.mp4 ./subdir/
```

But what if I wish to change extension of these files instead of moving? I'd like syntax like that to exist:

```
mv ./(*).mp4 "./@1.webm"
```

Here, parentheses do capturing a matched string, and `@1` will be replaced by that string.

Of course, I've just made up such syntax, and that command will not work.

So, here is a **question**: How do I re-use matched pattern? If there is no similar syntax, what solution of this task should I use? Before You suggest: I do know one, by using cycle `for f in ./*.mp4 ; do mv "$f" "${f/.mp4/.webm}" ; done`, but I'd like to see more compact solutions than that one.

I'm not quite sure, how pattern matching works in shell, so I doubt, is there any simpler solution than `for` cycle mentioned above.

Comment: Sorry, I confused the tool. It must be Perl-rename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`zsh` lets you make the loop shorter.

```
# Compare to
# for f in ./*.mp4 ; do mv "$f" "${f/.mp4/.webm}" ; done
for f (./*.mp4) mv "$f" "$f:r.webm"
```

It also provides the `zmv` command (modeled after the Perl script in @glennjackman's answer).

```
autoload zmv
zmv './(*).mp4' './$1.webm'
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. For anyone (like me), who are not so familiar with zsh, it is useful to also check out [that thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30840651/what-does-autoload-do-in-zsh).

Answer (score 0):

With the perl `rename`

```sh
rename -n 's{(.+)\.mp4}{./subdir/$1.webm}' *.mp4
```

If it looks right, remove the `-n` flag.

This is not pre-installed by default:

- MacOS: using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh): `brew install rename`
- Ubuntu: `apt install rename`

Comment: Don't think this is an answer to my question, I'd expect solution for bash shell on stock system (or zsh, because I'm working on Mac). Or maybe perl is pre-installed on some systems? In my case `rename` is unknown command (`zsh: command not found: rename`)

Comment: `rename` isn't part of Perl, but is a script written *in* Perl. Perl is preinstalled on most systems (including macOS), but `rename` itself is not preinstalled on macOS.